# How to create table from remote DB in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to create some tables from a remote SQL Server in my own sandbox, can anyone tell me how to get that done?

For example, I know there is a way called database link can implement this function, but can I do in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is on the Remote SQL server is get the table design.
Right click on it and use Create To. Copy Pasta the code and use in your database.
Just need to modify the database name

After that you will only need to merge the data in if that is what you are also hoping to do.